# 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'region'

Tags: python, tiktok

```
!pip install TikTokApi 
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
verifyFp = "aaa"
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(custom_verifyFp=verifyFp, user_test_endpoints=True)
api.by_hashtag('funny')
```

Currently using 4.0.1 version of TikTokApi. I was able to get the function api.get_user to work but when I tried to call api.by_hashtag I got the following error. Has anyone else seen the error and know how to deal with it? The verifyFp = "aaa"  code can be extracted by visiting tiktok.com and get the s_v_web_id value from cookies

Thank you!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-3ba9a6be8f4f> in <module>
----> 1 api.by_hashtag('funny')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py in by_hashtag(self, hashtag, count, offset, **kwargs)
    952         kwargs["custom_device_id"] = device_id
    953         id = self.get_hashtag_object(hashtag)["challengeInfo"]["challenge"]["id"]
--> 954         response = []
    955 
    956         required_count = count

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py in get_hashtag_object(self, hashtag, **kwargs)
   1002         api_url = "{}node/share/tag/{}?{}&{}".format(
   1003             BASE_URL, quote(hashtag), self.__add_url_params__(), urlencode(query)
-> 1004         )
   1005         data = self.get_data(url=api_url, **kwargs)
   1006         if data["challengeInfo"].get("challenge") is None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TikTokApi\tiktok.py in __add_url_params__(self)
   1653             "region": self.region or "US",
   1654             "priority_region": "",
-> 1655             "os": "ios",
   1656             "referer": "",
   1657             "root_referer": "",

AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'region'
```

Comment: Got it to work on my mac